# form data with file control not uploading

Tags: spring-boot, angular4-forms

I am trying to upload a form with file and form data using angular4 and spring boot. i set the content type as a `multipart/form-data` but still its showing me 400 error.

**My angular side is**

```
this.formobj["userID"] = this.userId;
this.formobj["userName"] = this.addfrm.value.userName;
this.formobj["userDescription"] = this.addfrm.value.userDes;
this.formobj["files"] = this.addfrm.value.image;

let type = new HttpHeaders();
type.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');


this.http.post(this.Core_URL + '/updateUserWithFile', this.formobj, {headers: type})
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("** form submited");
    console.log(data);
    this.clearShareObj();
    this.r.navigateByUrl('home');
  });
```

}

**Server side**

Server side i am using spring boot

```
@PostMapping("/updateUserWithFile")
private FunctionInfo updateUserWithFile(@RequestBody  UserInfo  userInfo) {
   System.out.println("ok");
   int userId = userInfo.getUserId();
   String userName = userInfo.getUserName();
   MultipartFile[] files; = userInfo.getFile();
}
```

**DomainClass**

```
 public class UserInfo {
 private Integer userID;
 private String userName;
 private String userDescription;
 private MultipartFile[] files;
 }
```

After submitting its showing me the below headers. content type is not setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to set headers. This might help you,

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

and

```
 constructor(private http: Http){}
```

inside your method use

```
const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'});

return this.http.post(this.Core_URL + '/updateUserWithFile', this.formobj, 
{headers: headers})
.subscribe(data => {
    console.log("** form submited");
    console.log(data);
    this.clearShareObj();
    this.r.navigateByUrl('home');
});
```